# No internet connection for Ubuntu 18.04.06 LTS (VirtualBox) after update & upgrade

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet

I am using Ubuntu in my VirtualBox on my Windows 10 Laptop. I set it up ages ago and never really had any issues or if I did, I found a way to solve it. But just now I started my virtual machine, did some stuff and then decided to run sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade. And now I can't get my virtual Ubuntu (18.04.06 LTS) connected to the internet anymore. I am using the standard VirtualBox network settings, meaning I have one network adapter, attached to NAT. Never changed anything about that. Also, I am using a wired connection.

To be honest, I don't really know where to start at, like what commands can I run to get some output that helps me to identify the problem? All I see is the network symbol in the upper right corner with a question mark, but that's about it....
What can I do to get to the bottom of this? Any help appreciated since I am a complete beginner with Linux/Ubuntu....

Thanks in advance,
marvin

ip addr output looks like this:

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:a0:f0:16 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s3
valid_lft 86100sec preferred_lft 86100sec
inet6 fe80::d1fd:b68:85d9:c51d/64 scope link noprefixroute
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: OK. Let's assume that your update changed something and let's start by checking where the outbound traffic stops. Are you familiar with the CLI? Try this: nslookup www.google.com

Comment: There's another command wich will help you to determine where the traffic stops. If you enter "tracepath www.google.com" you'll get a list of the network devices traversed by the packets. The list will end with a few "no reply" lines and the command will eventually drop a "Too many hops" message.  Don't worry: the important information is in the few first lines. An isolated VM will show "Temporary failure in name resolution". Is this your case?.

Comment: Neither of these command give any result. nslookup results in ";; connection timed out; no servers could be reached" and tracepath results in Name or service not known.

Comment: Does internet still work for the host(windows)? If your router is giving out IP addresses you could probably switch to a bridged adapter and let it pull an IP address from your router (instead of your host) to get you back on the internet. Then you may be able to narrow down the problem. `ip route` shows your routing, should show a a ping-able gateway address. Right-clicking that network symbol should give you some device details. I've used virtualbox for years too, but I've ONLY used static IPs with a bridged adapter - also an option until you get a better handle.

Comment: I remember similar behaviour years ago after some crash. Try to force a new  MAC address asigned by VB to the Ubuntu box. Select de VM and go to /Settings/Network/Advanced/. You'll find a button with two "chasing-their-tails" arrows wich generates a new random MAC.

Answer (score 0):

How about a couple ping test?

example:
ping 8.8.8.8
-then
ping google.com

May be internet is working, but DNS is broke

Also, what are the outputs of ifconfig, or ip addr?

Regards,

Comment: If I try to ping 8.8.8.8, I get "sendmsg: Operation not permitted". Ip addr output pasted in question above

Comment: This is not an answer it is a comment.